# How to fetch subcollection dynamically in firebase firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How to fetch subCollection on client side dynamically when subCollection is created serverside.

Since I'll be creating subcollection dynamically I will not be knowing name of such subCollection, how to fetch such subCollection in my react. Js code if I am using firebase firestore.

I am new in firebase firestore please help me solve this.

Comment: It's not possible to query Firestore without knowing the name of the collection (and subcollection) of the documents to query.  Compared to SQL, that would be similar to trying to select from a table whose name you don't know.  If your data model depends on dynamically generated collection names, that is not really compatible with the way Firestore works.  You should restructure your data so that all variability happens only in fields of documents.

Comment: Can you please suggest me any other alternative?

Comment: As I said, don't use variable collection names. You don't have enough information in your question to make a specific recommendation.